# Multipart file upload from java server to S3 bucket gets corrupted(Even after enable multipart/form-data in API Gateway)

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-s3, aws-api-gateway, multipartform-data

I am currently using AWS SDK to upload file from java server to S3 bucket.In my local machine the file gets uploaded correctly and is accessable.But when i dockerize my Application and run it in Fargate the issue starts.All the files that i upload gets corrupted.

I figured out that you have to allow multipart/form-data in API Gateway,but even after the issue persists,Any helping hands would be really appreciated

```
AmazonS3 s3Client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard().build();
ObjectMetadata metadata = new ObjectMetadata();
metadata.setContentDisposition("inline");
metadata.setContentLength(file.length());
InputStream targetStream = new FileInputStream(file);
metadata.setContentType("image/jpeg");
PutObjectRequest request = new PutObjectRequest(bucketName, bucketFolderName + attachmentName, file);
request.setMetadata(metadata);
s3Client.putObject(request.withCannedAcl(CannedAccessControlList.PublicRead));
```

[image: This is how i am calling the api]

[image: Headers]
[image: API Gateway settings]

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue,Every time you update API Gateway you have to Deploy it again